# Mysql select from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 difrrent table structures, I will call them A,B,C.

I need to do a search on all those 3 tables at the same time, let's that I need to:

A.name LIKE %Google%  B.company LIKE%Google% and C.company LIKE%Google%

It's posibile to get a query out for the "query type" mentionated?

Best Regards!

Here is what i'm looking for

```
Select from table A where A.name LIKE %something% inner join B on b.company LIKE %something% and after that I need to do the samething for table C..but I don't know how...
```

The query:

```
 SELECT name FROM firmen WHERE name LIKE '%Felsengartenkellerei Besigheim eG%'
  UNION
   SELECT firma FROM daten WHERE firma LIKE '%Felsengartenkellerei Besigheim eG%'
UNION
  SELECT firma FROM ver WHERE firma LIKE '%Felsengartenkellerei Besigheim eG%'
```

Comment: Can you give a little more detail as to what you're trying to do? Are these 3 tables related in some way? A schema structure would be super helpful.

Comment: Are those 3 tables independent of each other? Just to elaborate dlo's vomment...is there any foreign key relationships in either of the table?

Comment: No, completly diffrent tables structures...I need to do a search on them... and If I found what the user it's looking for I need to display it! Here are the fields name that need to be searched:
For table A -> name for table B -> company  for table C -> company

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, since we don't have the schema, but presumably A is a table of companies, where the 'name' field corresponds to a foreign-key 'company' field in both  B and C, if that is so then you'd some thing like:

```
SELECT * FROM A, B, C
  WHERE A.name LIKE '%Google%' 
  AND B.company = A.name
  AND C.company = A.name
```

Edit, so from your comment in the question where you say they're *not* foreign keys, you want to select all rows that have a particular filed 'LIKE' Google, you just do them one at a time:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE name    LIKE '%Google%'
SELECT * FROM B WHERE company LIKE '%Google%'
SELECT * FROM B WHERE company LIKE '%Google%'
```

If all 3 of these tables had the same schema (or they have a few fields in common and you just select those in a corresponding order), you could take the UNION of these 3 queries if you wanted to join the results together.

Suppose all 3 of them have a 'url' or 'webaddr' field, and they have 'desc', 'description', and 'info' fields respectively:

```
SELECT url, desc            FROM A WHERE name    LIKE '%Google%'
UNION
SELECT webaddr, description FROM B WHERE company LIKE '%Google%'
UNION
SELECT url, info            FROM B WHERE company LIKE '%Google%'
```

There's a nice explanation of the semantics of UNION and UNION ALL in MySQL on [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-union-keyword.htm)

Comment: Can you please give me an example with UNION  how to join the results together please, I haven't slept for about 50h so I can't think to much now.Thank you

Comment: My query looks like this:

SELECT name FROM firmen WHERE name    LIKE %Felsengartenkellerei Besigheim eG%
UNION
SELECT company FROM daten WHERE company LIKE %Felsengartenkellerei Besigheim eG%
UNION
SELECT company FROM ver WHERE company LIKE %Felsengartenkellerei Besigheim eG%

An the error:
--------------------------
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%Felsengartenkellerei Besigheim eG%
UNION
SELECT company FROM daten WHERE compan' at line 1 
-----------------------

Comment: you need quotes around your LIKE string, probably better if you put your full query in your original post, indented so we get highlighting